Entra B2C Custom Policy - Trying to add Custom Claims for Sign Up that save to User Properties
I am trying to use the Sign up using invitation sample for B2C.  We only want users to be able to sign up via invitation.
In my Entra B2C tenant, I have two User Attributes assigned:

AdvisorId
ClientId

I would like to persist these values on signup, and then return them as claims on sign in.
For my sign in user flow, I have already checked them to enable them as claims.
For generating my token, I have successfully added the claims and they look like this:

{
  ...
  "name": "Johnny Test",
  "https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId": "12345",
  "https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId": "67890"
}


The problem is on the redeem script.  What I need it to do is, using the script from the example as a base, modify it so the incoming claims are saved to the user attributes.
Where I am
I have added definitions for my claim and the attribute:

    <ClaimType Id="advisorId">
        <DisplayName>User's Advisor Id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId"/>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId"/>
        <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId"/>
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Advisor identifier (ID)</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
    
    <ClaimType Id="clientId">
        <DisplayName>User's Client Id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId"/>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId"/>
        <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId"/>
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Client identifier (ID)</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
    
    <ClaimType Id="advisorIdAttribute">
        <DisplayName>User's Advisor Id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="AdvisorId"/>
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Advisor identifier (ID)</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
    
    <ClaimType Id="clientIdAttribute">
        <DisplayName>User's Client Id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="ClientId"/>
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Client identifier (ID)</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>


Then, I have my mapping defined to translate from the claim to the attribute.

    <ClaimsTransformation Id="MapAdvisorIdClaimToUserAttribute" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="advisorId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="advisorIdAttribute" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
    
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="MapClientIdClaimToUserAttribute" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientIdAttribute" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>


Here's the modified open id configuration

    <ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Self Referenced ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
                <DisplayName>Self referenced ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="None" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="METADATA">https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_INV_redeem/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <!-- claims to read from the id_token_hint-->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name"/>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="advisorId" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId"/>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientId" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId"/>
                </OutputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>


And then at the bottom where the comments say to define the claims on the token, I have the following:

    <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInWithIdTokenHint" />
        <UserJourneyBehaviors>
            <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="111...111" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="true" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
            <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
        </UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
            <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <!--Sample: Set the input claims to be read from the id_token_hint-->
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                
                <!--
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="advisorId" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/advisorId"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientId" PartnerClaimType="https://schemas.mydomain.com/identity/client/clientId"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </RelyingParty>


Here's where I'm having the issue.  I'm trying to get those claims to map so they save to the user attributes.  Here's my modifications.

    <ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <!-- Self Asserted page for Signup from an email invite and id_token_hint -->
            <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpFromEmailInvite">
                <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
                    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Signup</Item>
                    <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <InputClaimsTransformations>
                    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyEmailAddress" />
                </InputClaimsTransformations>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" />
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="advisorIdAttribute" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientIdAttribute" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="MapAdvisorIdClaimToUserAttribute" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="MapClientIdClaimToUserAttribute" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
                    <!-- write the user object to the directory -->
                    <!-- <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SendSignupEvent" /> -->
                    <!-- notify backend system of user creation -->
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>


When I try to upload the policy, I get the following error:

Claim Type "advisorId" is the output claim of the relying party's technical profile, but it is not an output claim in any of the steps of user journey "SignInWithIdTokenHint".

I get the same error for client id.
The claims are defined as the output of IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims as you can see above, and the user journey is unchanged:


    <UserJourneys>
        <!-- UserJourney to redeem the email invite. It uses id_token_hint to validate the id_token passed -->
        <UserJourney Id="SignInWithIdTokenHint">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <!-- Read the input claims from the id_token_hint-->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="GetClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" />

    ...


What am I missing in order to get this to pass verification, and what am I missing to get the two claims to save into user attributes?

Why do you have "advisorIdAttribute" and "advisorId"?
You just need one.
In the TP, you output "advisorIdAttribute", but in the RP, you output "advisorId".
That's what the error is telling you.
